# What is the value of $[S^3/G] \in \pi_3(Sphere)$ for a finite subgroup $G \subset SU(2)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, stable-homotopy

Let $G\subset \mathrm{SU}(2)$ be a finite group. (These are famously classified through the McKay correspondence.) The Lie group framing of $\mathrm{SU}(2) = S^3$ descends to the quotient manifold $S^3 / G$, at least after getting some "left"s and "right"s in the correct places.

Every framed $k$-manifold determines a class in the $k$th stable homotopy group of spheres $\pi_k(\text{Sphere})$. For example, $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ with its Lie group framing provides a generator of $\pi_3(\text{Sphere}) = \mathbb{Z}/24$.

What are the values of the homotopy-group classes determined by the framed 3-manifolds $S^3/G$? How do these values relate to other Lie theoretic data like the rank or (dual) Coxeter number of the ADE Dynkin diagram?

Comment: The finite subgoups of $\operatorname{SU}(2) $ have been classified by Felix Klein, slightly before McKay...

Comment: @abx Thanks for the correction. I hadn't meant that the classification was due to McKay, only that I wanted to remind that it is convenient to sort them in terms of ADE data.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic again, but the correspondence in terms of ADE goes back (at least) to P. Duval (around 1930).

Comment: Could you please explain why "Every framed k-manifold determines a class in the kth stable homotopy group of spheres $\pi_k(Sphere)$", or give a reference to some book?

Comment: @abx Good to know. It is a fairly common phenomenon that mathematics is not named after its inventor...

Comment: @aglearner It is the type of fact I sort of grew up with. In deed, the statement is that the group $\Omega_k^{fr}$ of stably-framed $k$-manifolds up to stably-framed cobordism is isomorphic to the stable homotopy group $\pi_k^s$ of spheres. In his answer below, Alex Suciu cites a paper of Seade and Steer, which calls the map $\Omega_k^{fr} \to \pi_k^s$ the "Pontryagin construction" and cites Milnor's book *Topology from the differential viewpoint*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer can be found in Theorem 2.1 from a paper of José Seade and Brian Steer (*Complex singularities and the framed cobordism class of compact quotients of $3$-dimensional Lie groups by discrete subgroups*, Comment. Math. Helv. **65** (1990), no. 3, 349–374, available [here](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PID=GDZPPN002067641)): If $G$ is the cyclic group of order $r$, then $S^3/G$ represents $r$ times a generator of $\pi_3^s=\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$, whereas if $G$ is the $\langle p,q,r\rangle$ triangle group, then $S^3/G$ represents $(p+q+r-1)$ times a generator of $\pi_3^s$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this number $r$ or $(p+q+r-1)$ is the number of complex irreps of $G$, which in terms of the ADE classification is one more than the rank of the compact Dynkin diagram.

Comment: Quick reality check: Take $G=I^*$ (the binary icosahedral group of order 120), so that $S^3/G=\Sigma(2,3,5)$ is the Poincaré homology sphere.  Then the corresponding Dynkin diagram is $E_8$, and $2+3+5-1=9=8+1$.  Yep, that works.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason I wanted to say things in terms of the Dynkin diagram is that there is a moonshine-type construction that takes in certain Dynkin data and produces certain modular objects, and which might, in some yet-to-be understood way, factor through some geometric objects e.g. 3-manifolds. I had hoped to go (Dynkin data) -> (S^3/G) -> (modular object), but this seems not to work, or at least I need to think more.