# How does quotienting by a finite subgroup act on the framed-cobordism class of a group manifold?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, stable-homotopy, quantum-field-theory, cobordism

Let $G$ be a connected simple connected compact Lie group, and $\Gamma \subset G$ a finite subgroup. Then (the underlying manifold of) $G$ can be framed by right-invariant vector fields, and this framing descends to the quotient manifold $G/\Gamma$. Let $[G]$ and $[G/\Gamma]$ represent the corresponding classes in $\mathrm{Mfr}$, the Thom spectrum of framed cobordism, or use the same notation for their images in $\mathrm{MString}$ or $\mathrm{TMF}$.

In [a prior MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320706/), I learned that when $G = \mathrm{SU}(2)$, the following equality holds in $\mathrm{Mfr}$:

$$ [G/\Gamma] = [G] \times \#\{\text{conjugacy classes in }\Gamma\}.$$

I can give a physical argument suggesting that the above equality should hold in $\mathrm{TMF}$ for arbitrary $G$.

**Question:** Does the above equality hold in $\mathrm{Mfr}$ for arbitrary $G$? How about in $\mathrm{MString}$ or $\mathrm{TMF}$?

---

*Edit:* In the comments, Andre Henriques asks about my "physical argument". I will outline it here. It is premised on a conjectural description of $\mathrm{TMF}$ due to Stolz and Teichner, based suggestions of Witten and Segal: the $n$th space of the TMF spectrum is conjecturally equivalent to the moduli space of $(1+1)$D $\mathcal N=(0,1)$  SQFTs with gravitational anomaly equal to $n$ times the gravitational anomaly of a single chiral Majoron. Warning: there as yet is no mathematical definition of "$(1+1)$D $\mathcal N=(0,1)$  SQFT", let alone of their moduli space. But if there were such a mathematical definition, then it would be true that these moduli spaces would compile into an $E_\infty$ ring spectrum, which I will call $\mathrm{SQFT}$, equipped with maps $\mathrm{MString} \to \mathrm{SQFT}$ and $\mathrm{SQFT} \to \mathrm{MF}$ and $\mathrm{SQFT} \to \mathrm{KO}[[q]]$; these maps are among the evidence for the conjecture.

In any case, the String orientation $\mathrm{MString} \to \mathrm{SQFT}$ sends a String manifold $M$ to the $\mathcal{N} = (0,1)$ sigma model with target $M$. (The maps $\mathrm{SQFT} \to \mathrm{KO}[[q]]$ and $\mathrm{SQFT} \to \mathrm{MF}$ correspond respectively to compactifying on $S^1$ and on an elliptic curve, always with nonbounding Spin structure.) The field content of this sigma model consists of a boson (worldsheet scalar) $\phi$ valued in $M$ together with an antichiral fermion (worldsheet spinor) $\psi$ valued in $\phi^*\mathrm{T}_M$. The classical EOMs are that $\phi$ is harmonic and $\psi$ is antiholomorphic.

When $M = G$ is a group manifold, you get a "supersymmetric WZW model" at "level $k=0$". By using the right-invariant framing, you can use a change of coordinates to decouple the boson from the fermion. The sigma model is always a dynamical (nonconformal) QFT, with massive degrees of freedom. But RG flow is a homotopy in $\mathrm{SQFT}$, and you can flow the level-$k$ supersymmetric WZW model to the IR, where, after decoupling, it flows to a level-$k$ full WZW times the SCFT of an antichiral fermion valued in $\mathfrak{g} = \mathrm{Lie}(G)$. In the level-0 case, the WZW term is simply the vacuum, and the sigma model with target $G$ flows in the IR to a free-fermion theory.

The sigma model with target $G/\Gamma$ is the result of gauging the $G$-sigma model with by the manifest $\Gamma$ symmetry. Under RG flow, this will flow to a $\Gamma$-symmetry of the free fermion model. Which symmetry? In the UV, the symmetry is manifestly nonanomalous, and so it is nonanomalous in the IR, and the only natural nonanomalous action is the trivial one.

So in the IR, we are gauging the trivial $\Gamma$-action on the 2D SCFT consisting of an antichiral fermion in $\mathfrak{g}$. Since the action is trivial, it decouples, and the result is $($pure 2D $\Gamma$-gauge theory$) \times \overline{\mathrm{Fer}}(\mathfrak{g})$. Pure finite group 2D gauge theory was studied in detail by Frobenius in the late 19th century. Frobenius showed in particular that pure gauge theory in 2D is equivalent to a direct sum of $\#\{$conjugacy classes$\}$ many copies of the vacuum 2D TQFT.

The claim follows in $\mathrm{SQFT}$, and so in $\mathrm{TMF}$ if you believe that $\mathrm{SQFT} = \mathrm{TMF}$. I don't know whether the claim should or should not hold in $\mathrm{MString}$ or $\mathrm{Mfr}$.

Comment: @LSpice It is if an experienced MO user had not much time to dash off a question. But, certainly, if you and I were coauthoring, you can rest assured that I would have plenty of macros, and plenty of <tt>\mathrm</tt>s.

Comment: Is it obvious that framing always descends?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I think this is obvious if I get "left" and "right" in the correct spots. I have a good chance of getting it backwards. Let's see. A left-invariant vector field is arranged by taking a vector and translating by acting from the right. If I quotient by the left action --- well, that's the action that manifestly preserves left-invariant vector fields. Hrm, looks like I more likely than not got them backwards in my question, since surely $G/\Gamma$ means quotient from the right.

Comment: Per @LSpice's comment, I have romanized some names. Per მამუკაჯიბლაძე's comment, I have changed a "left" to a "right".

Comment: "I can give a physical argument suggesting that..." I would be quite interested to see the argument. Would you be able to explain what you have in mind, either in a comment, or as a footnote to your question?

Comment: 1. What is MF? Is that a typo for TMF? 2. It is conjectured that $[G]=0$ for all but finitely many $G$. Is this still open? [Here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1191418762) is a weak result. 3. Does your heuristic apply more generally than groups? Perhaps for some elements of $Mfr(X)$?

Comment: @BenWieland 1. It is not a typo: I mean the graded ring of modular forms, or rather ordinary cohomology with coefficients that graded ring. 2. I have no idea. Thank you for the link! 3. I'm not sure which heuristic you mean? In general, the RG flow from a sigma model is some complicated thing. Well, it might flow to zero, or it might flow to some model which is a CFT but is hard to describe. Example: if my story is correct, then already non-simply-connected groups flow to some nontrivial TFT. So for general non-simply-connected manifolds, all bets are off.

Comment: 2. FWIW The author I linked, Minami, polished off the theorem in 2016. I heard it asserted as a theorem long before that, but probably the speaker secretly meant localized at a large prime, already proved by Knapp or Ossa c1980. (Of course RHS=0 doesn't mean LHS=0 is an easy statement. But it's not appealing.) 3. You seem to be talking about a single point in SQFT, but if the heuristic applied to families, you might be able to produce interesting families which are nontrivial even if their constituent points are trivial.

Comment: 1. MF vs TMF. That's pretty weird. There's no spectum with homotopy groups MF, is there? do you mean tensor $\mathbb Q$? Of course, you could build $H(MF)$, but that sounds implausible. $H\mathbb Z\wedge TMF$ is something you could wind up with if you're trying to descend to $TMF$.

Comment: @BenWieland, Yes, let's say that I meant $MF \otimes \mathbb C$. Although I had thought that there was a general procedure that took graded rings to cohomology theories.  Let $MF^j_{\mathbb{Z}}$ mean the set of modular forms of weight $j/2$ with integral $q$-expansion. Then certainly there is a cohomology theory $h^n(X) := \bigoplus_{i+j=n} H^i(X; MF^j_{\mathbb{Z}})$, isn't there? Other than that perhaps I mean $n=i-j$, I think this is the one I mean.

Comment: 3. In principle, it is a very rich question to understand families of SQFTs. In some sense, that is the reason for pursuing this conjectural relationship to TMF. But my argument involved RG flowing to the IR, and computing there. RG flow is a sort of funny thing. First, it is just hard to work out the IR limit of an (S)QFT in general. For instance, it is common that the UV theory is sort of "affine" (in the algebrogeometric sense of being determined by its local observables) but that the IR theory might have hard-to-describe nonlocal operators. (In (1+1)d I think this isn't too bad.)

Comment: Second, RG flow is discontinuous. The "Zamolodchikov c-theorem" exhibits a (probably Morse--Bott?) function on the moduli space of (S)QFTs, called "$c$", so that RG flow is Morse flow for $c$. So it should not surprise you that you can start with a smooth family, and RG flow every point in it to the IR, and you'll end up with a family that jumps from critical point to critical point.

Comment: 2. Thanks. I think I found the paper, but my local library is being ornery. The Minami paper you linked to cites a lemma in a paper my local library is being particularly ornery about that seems to do a version, perhaps just for central subgroups of $G$, of my question...

Comment: Yes, there is an ordinary homology with coefficients some $\mathbb Z$ form of MF, but... it would take an awful lot to convince me that you mean this. Do you have a link where someone considers this object?

Comment: "Do you have a link where someone considers this object?" No. I have plenty of links where someone considers things like de Rham cohomology with coefficients in $MF \otimes \mathbb C$. Certainly that's the thing that's most natural from the physics.